# Get an Android applications running Activities without holding static references

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to get an Android applications running or not running `Activity` objects without holding a static context to them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(this,Activity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

if pi==null then is not running

Im not shure. I dont have time to try.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this did not work, it always seems to return null.

Comment: Also you can do sendstickybroadcast(intent) and anywhere can do intent = registerreceiver(null,"your.intent.action.name")

Answer (score 0):

You always need a Context, and there's always one around. Applications *are* Contexts, Activities are also contexts, Views have contexts, Service and BroadcastReciever entry points have a Context as their first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Derive all of your activities from a common base class (I do this in all projects anyway to encapsulate common functionality).  In onPause and onResume, report to a common location.  You can keep a list of strings representing the open activities as opposed to holding hard references to them.  Since there could be multiples, you should probably save this information to a structure that can tell you the number of each activity instances as well.

If you need to send a command to one of these open activities (or all of them) you can have them register a broadcast receiver.

Comment: In that case, you can register and unregister your broadcast receiver in the base class, and then anyone who is active will receive the broadcast